# onMessageReceived() not getting called

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Like some others, I too can't seem to get GCM to work. In particular, I cannot see why execution is not reaching GcmListenerService.onMessageReceived().

I have followed the official docs and have managed to (I think) do the following correctly:

- get a registration token using InstanceID
- send this token back to my *local* Rails server for storage
- subsequently, use this same token to send a message (no notification) using GCM.

The relevant bits of code are as follows. Please let me know if something is amiss.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<!-- GCM specific -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.gradians.prepwell.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.gradians.prepwell.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="com.gradians.prepwell" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".services.MyGcmListenerService" android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
</intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".services.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
</intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".services.RegisterService"
android:exported="false" />
```

**MyGcmListenerService.java (not getting called)**

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    Log.i("debug", "onMessageReceived") ;
}
}
```

**Rails Code**

```
def post_potd
api_key = "AIz......-_Y"
gcm = GCM.new(api_key)
reg_ids = Device.all.map(&:gcm_token)
payload = { 
  data: { message: "Hello Dude!" }
}   
response = gcm.send reg_ids, payload 
render json: response, status: :ok 
end
```

**The JSON Response to above Rails code** seems to be ok (status_code = 200, response='success' etc.). So, I am guessing GCM has no issues with the request that was posted.

But are there any other common pitfalls in GCM integration that one must watch for? And how can one check for them?

I thought I had done everything right. But I have obviously have missed something. Hence, any insights / tips / advice would be most helpful.

Thanks 
Abhinav.

Comment: Just make sure the token you are sending too is correct, try a string literal.

Comment: Few clarifications: Are there any indications in the logcat that the message is arriving at the device? Are you able to receive other notifications on the device you are using? Have you tried the Android app on another device?

Comment: Actually, it all worked out correctly. The problem was not in the code.

Comment: Actually, it all worked out correctly. The problem was not in the code. I was just sitting in a network dead zone when testing. Hence, whilst the notifications were getting sent to GCM, they were not getting to my device even after 10-15 minutes. But when I went outside, I would get the message / notification.

Comment: All in all, I learnt to accept the quirks of the GCM to device connection. Everything does not have to happen instantaneously.